# Outer-Measure inequality proof

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory

Let $E, F$ be two sets in $\mathbb{R}^d$. I am trying to show that for $\mu^*(E), \mu^*(F) < \infty$, we have: $$|\mu^*(E) - \mu^*(F)| \leq \mu^*(E\,\Delta \,F) $$

So this is doable for **measurable $E, F$** but what about the general case. If the only information we have about the two sets is that their outer-measure is finite, then **we cannot use countable additivity in line** $(1)$

\begin{align}
  |\mu^*(E) - \mu^*(F)|
    &=    \left|\left(\mu^*\left(E \setminus F\right) + \mu^*\left(E \cap F\right)\right) - \left(\mu^*\left(E \cap F\right) + \mu^*\left(F \setminus E\right)\right) \right| \ \ \ (1) \\
    &=    \left|\mu^*\left(E \setminus F\right) - \mu^*\left(F \setminus E\right)\right| \\
    &\leq \left|\mu^*\left(E \setminus F\right)\right| + \left|\mu^*\left(F \setminus E\right)\right| \\
    &=    \mu^*\left(E \setminus F\right) + \mu^*\left(F \setminus E\right) \\
    &=    \mu^*\left(\left(E \setminus F\right) \cup \left(F \setminus E\right)\right) \\
    &=    \mu^*\left(E\, \Delta \, F\right)
\end{align}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$  \mu^*(E) - \mu^*(F)
    \le    \mu^*(E \setminus F)  $ (because, $E \subset F \cup (E\setminus F)$) $\le   \mu^*(E \Delta F)$. Similarly, $  \mu^*(F) - \mu^*(E)
    \le   \mu^*(E \Delta F) $, so $  |\mu^*(E) - \mu^*(F)|
    \le    \mu^*(E \setminus F) \le   \mu^*(E \Delta F) $.

Comment: How did you go from $ \mu^*(E)  \le    \mu^*\{ F \cup (E\setminus F)\}$ 
to  $ \mu^*(E)   \le    \mu^*(F) +  \mu^*(E \setminus F) $.
What property of "outer-measure" did you?

Comment: $\mu^{*} (A\cup B)\leq \mu^{*}(A)+\mu^{*}(B)$ and $A \subseteq B$ implies $\mu^{*} (A) \le \mu^{*} (B)$. @Note